# Handle caret position in content editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, caret

I have this content editable div in HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="TextOnlyPage"></div>
```

And heres my jquery code

```
var rxp = new RegExp("(([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)|([0-9]+))", "gm");
$('#TextOnlyPage').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#TextOnlyPage').children().each(function() {
            if ( $(this).is("div") ) {
                $(this).contents().unwrap();
            }});
        $('#TextOnlyPage').append("<br/>");
    }
        $('#TextOnlyPage').children().contents().unwrap();
        var $this = $(this);
        var content = $this.html();
        $this.html(content.replace(rxp, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>"));});
```

Problem is the caret position, because when it apply span tags around numbers in string.replace method then cursor goes to the start of the content editable `div`. Also it can't goes to next line while I press enter key.

I know I can handle it through `range` and `selection` objects, but can't find a useful resource to understand how these objects works.

Kindly either provide me solution for this problem and it will be better if the solution in angularjs, or provide me a resource where I can understand range and selection objects with working examples.

Comment: I assume you mean the greater than [`>`] and less than [`<`] characters since there isn't a caret [`^`] anywhere in this post?

Comment: @ethorn10 By caret position, the OP is referring to the position of the insertion point in the text box.

Comment: @ethorn10 Sorry I didn't get you..!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue as you did a while ago, to undertand how `range` and `selection` works I recommend you to take a look at MDN docs [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) and [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)

One reliable way of detecting change in a `contentEditable` div is the event `input`. One issue I found when listenning for `keyUp` and preventing the default behavior for certain `keyCode` is that they are tons of them and it's very hard to cover all use cases.

What I prefer to do is to let the normal event being processed, save the caret position, get the text value and replace the parts that needs to be highlighted and then set the caret position back.

Here is a simple example

```
var contentEditable = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]');
contentEditable.addEventListener('input', onInput);

var onInput = function(e) {

    // this function will be called after the current call-stack
    // is finished, at that time the user input will be inserted
    // in the content editable
    setTimeout(function() {

        // save the caret position

        var text = contentEditable.innerText;
        // perform all your replacement on `text`
        contentEditable.innerHTML = text;

        // set the caret position back
    }, 0);
}
```

I also wrote two handy method `getCaretOffsetWithin` and `setCaretPositionWithin` to help manipulate the caret when you want to perform some DOM manipulation and re-position the caret at its initial value after the processing.

You can check them on this gist [contenteditable-utils.js](https://gist.github.com/gsouquet/664ce3284fefa38e52d4)

Comment: Thanks for the code, dude. Saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources from MDN: [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) and [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range).

I've created this [JSFiddle to demonstrate re-positioning the caret](http://jsfiddle.net/5yq86tba/5/).

It doesn't work for all cases (e.g. on enter, selecting a range with shift + arrow ...) but it should already give you some ideas.

Here's an example from MDN about creating selections:

```
/* Select all STRONG elements in an HTML document */

var strongs = document.getElementsByTagName("strong");
var s = window.getSelection();

if(s.rangeCount > 0) s.removeAllRanges();

for(var i = 0; i < strongs.length; i++) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(strongs[i]);
    s.addRange(range);
}
```

As a sidenote, working with `contentEditable` will bring up more troubles in the future, I suggest doing your best to find alternatives to it. Also, be sure to notice the limited browser support warnings in the links I provided.